# How to use Laravel $request->whenHas() method?

Tags: php, laravel, request

I am parsing through the Laravel request object to identify if any inputs were entered by the user, so that I may update the model with only the updated values.

Currently I am using:

```
if (isset($request->$field) && $request->$field != $model->$field) {
     $model->$field = $request->$field;
}
```

and I recently found a Laravel request method [whenHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present) that seems to be a more efficient way to accomplish this task.

I searched the web and [stackoverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) for examples but only found the basic construct.  I am new to OOP but do understand this would be related to closures/callbacks.

FYI, in my current code I have the isset() function since the response may contain a null value for the field that I am comparing against the model's related field value (my current code snippet is within a "foreach($fields as $field) function).

How would I accomplish this functionality with the whenHas method?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem I was experiencing is that validation would fail for unique fields when a user was 'updating' their model.  I attempted to address this by the 'whenHas()' method when there was a much simpler solution... simply adding the current user's info to the validation rule (e.g. `'email' => 'unique:table,email_column_to_check,id_to_ignore'`).

Answer (score 1):

```
$request->whenHas($field, function ($value) use ($field, $model) {
    $model->$field = $value;
});

// or PHP 7.4+

$request->whenHas($field, fn ($value) => $model->$field = $value);
```

If the request has the field the value of that input will be passed to your callback. This method does return the `$request` if the field does not exist, or it will return the `$request` or anything you return from the callback if it runs it (the field exists).

Though you may not really have to be doing this at all. If you have specific fields to check for you could iterate through `$request->only($fields)`.

Comment: I found out I can't implement this before invoking a type-hinted RequestClass (see below).  For some reason when I submit the form the model tries to update every field value even if it wasn't changed.  I type-hint a Laravel Request class in the controller action method parameters (e.g. public function update(ModelUpdateRequest $request) ), and this invokes the ModelUpdateRequest class, where I can then call the Validator functions.

Comment: When I create a data record, I can test for "UserName" uniqueness via Laravel's Validator just fine, but when I edit a record I find that I have to disable the unique fields in the View in order to not get an error (even if unique field values didn't change) because of a violation of Laravel's Validator "unique" rule.  I am developing a work around that is turning into a full fledged solution, but was hoping to avoid all of that if there was something built in that would address this issue.

Comment: the unique rule has a way to ignore the unique check on a record, otherwise we wouldn't be able to pass validation for unique when updating

Comment: Yes, but if a user changes the unique field values, it would introduce another error.  I resolved this by disabling fields that need unique values in the 'Edit' form (part 1 of my solution), and this works.  I'm developing part 2, which is to have the ability to edit unique fields.  Was hoping for a simpler solution, my code is available at https://github.com/GeorgeBroIV/pitcanasta (check out app/Http/cControllers, app/Http/Requests/ModelUpdateRequest.php, app/Traits/InputValidateTrait.php and app/Traits/ModelUpdateTrait.php)